# How do I use API post to bityep.com?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Why is the code below not working? Maybe something wrong with parameter?

```
let key = "LLLLLXXXXXXZZZZZZKEY"
let nonce = 3
let parameters: Parameters = ["api_key": key, "nonce": nonce]

let data = "method=getInfo&nonce=" + String(nonce)
let sign = generateHMAC(key: key, data: data)

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
  "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "Key": "LLLLLXXXXXXZZZZZZKEY",
  "Sign": sign,
]

Alamofire.request("https://bitye.com/api/1/bid", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).response { response in
  debugPrint(response.response)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it crashing? Is it not compiling? Is it printing something you don't expect? Any error messages? Please clarify by editing your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your request is incorrect. According to it's API it should be:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
]

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "api_key" : "API_KEY",
    "base" : "BTC",
    "counter" : "USD",
    "amount" : "1",
    "price" : "4000.11111"
]

let bidUrl = "https://bityep.com/api/1/bid"

Alamofire.request(bidUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).response { response in
  debugPrint(response.response)
}
```